# Convert specific word to HTML hyperlink using sed command

Tags: sed, html

I need to convert a word to HTML hyper text link .

Each occurrence of the word `page NNN` will be converted to `<a href="#pNNN">` where `NNN` is the page number.

So:

```
See page 107
```

Would become:

```
 See <a href="#p107">page 107</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/page ([0-9]+)/<a href="#p\1">page \1<\/a>/' file
```

You can redirect this to a new file using `> newfile` or use the `-i` option to modify the file in place.

Comment: you could also use `&` in place of `page \1` in the replacement